# Проблема с is_dir

Tags: php

Создаю в корне проекта вручную директорию (скажем dir1), задаю ей chmod 777, затем уже внутри этой директории создаю другие, используя php.
При проверке is_dir(dir1) выдаст true, а при проверке вложенных в нее папок (созданных с помощью php) выдает false...

В php выглядит так:

```
mkdir("$foldername", 0777, true);
```

//проверяю следующим образом:

```
$dir = "/dir1/$username";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            if (is_dir($entry) == true) {
               echo "DIRECTORY: ".$entry."\n";
            }
        }
     }
}
```

dir1 - директория, созданная вручную,
$username - директория, созданная php

Comment: как Вы проверяете, код в студию

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно просто отдохнуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну дык абсолютный путь же..  От корня..

```
$dir = "/dir1/$username";
```

И 100% такого просто нет..

Надо примерно так:

```
$dir = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(dirname(__FILE__), 'dir1', $username));
```

Ну или что-то такое..

А если проверка типа:

```
is_dir('dir1')
```

выдаёт true, тогда надо просто вот так:

```
$dir = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('dir1', $username));
```

P.S. использую implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, _бла_бла_бла) для того, чтобы точно работало на всех системах..

Comment: Увы, результат тот же :(

Comment: это не поможет, потому что проверка директорий идет уже ВНУТРИ `dir1/$username`

Answer (score 1):

Вообщето... Тезают смутные сомнения. Проверять ответ `mkdir` тоже надо, вы УВЕРЕНЫ, что папки создались?

сделайте дебаг простенький, выводите ВСЕ `$entry`

и еще, в мануале написано, что результаты этой функции кешируются, поэтому их рекомендуется очищать функцией `clearstatcache()`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_dir("$dir/$entry") == true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте сделаем вот так :

```
$dir = './dir1/'.$username.'/';

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir.$entry) === true) {
               echo 'DIRECTORY: '.$dir.$entry."\n";
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Всё это работает при условии, что в папке со сценарием лежит папка **dir1**, а в **dir1** есть папка с именем **$username**.